Optimizing recursive portal traversing
I am working on an engine that uses portals for rendering areas, called "rooms".
A room can have any number of portals, oriented in anyway, but the most common case are axis aligned portals at the outer walls,ceiling and flor of a room in any size.
Each portal consists of 4 vertices. The vertices are projected into clip space.
The algorithm works recursively (and to my surprise, iterative using a separate stack was atrociously slower)
For a given room, the clip rectangle is saved and applied to the portals to other rooms, so you get a nice shrinking clip rect for every subsequent portal.
When a room is visited multiple times, the room clip rectangle actually grows so the room gets a clip rectangle that spans the current and previous portal(s).
A room is collected for rendering as soon as it's visited for the first time.
void clamp_clipped_rect(const raid::float4& a, const raid::float4& b, raid::float4& clipport) {
        if((a.w > 0.0f) ^ (b.w > 0.0f)) {
            if(a.x < 0.0f && b.x < 0.0f) {
                clipport.x = -1.0f;
            } else {
                if(a.x > 0.0f && b.x > 0.0f) {
                    clipport.z = 1.0f;
                } else {
                    clipport.xz = float2(-1.0f, 1.0f);
                }
            }
            if(a.y < 0.0f && b.y < 0.0f) {
                clipport.y = -1.0f;
            } else {
                if(a.y > 0.0f && b.y > 0.0f) {
                    clipport.w = 1.0f;
                } else {
                    clipport.yw = float2(-1.0f, 1.0f);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    std::optional<float4> get_portal_clip_rect(const room_visibility_portal& portal, room_id parent, level_render_data& render_data) {
        ZoneScoped;
        const auto n = portal.normal;
        const auto view_angle = dot(render_data.view_position - float3(portal.corners[0]), n);
        if(view_angle <= 0) {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
        auto z_clip = 0;
        auto& room_vis = render_data.vis.visibility[portal.room];
        auto parent_vis = render_data.vis.visibility[parent].clipport;
        float4 clipport{ 1, 1, -1, -1 };
        std::array<float4, 4> portal_vertices;
        for(auto i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            auto& portal_vert = portal_vertices[i];
            portal_vert = render_data.view_projection * float4(float3(portal.corners[i]), 1.0f);
            if(portal_vert.w > 0.0f) {
                portal_vert.xy /= float2(portal_vert.w, -portal_vert.w);
                clipport.xy = glm::min(clipport.xy(), portal_vert.xy());
                clipport.zw = glm::max(clipport.zw(), portal_vert.xy());
            } else {
                z_clip |= 1 << i;
            }
        }

        if((z_clip & 0b1111) == 0b1111) {
            return std::nullopt;
        }

        if((z_clip | 0b1111) > 0) {
            for(auto i = 0u; i < 4; i++) {
                const auto& a = portal_vertices[i];
                const auto& b = portal_vertices[(i + 1) % 4];
                clamp_clipped_rect(a, b, clipport);
            }
        }

        if(!room_vis.active) {
            clipport.xy = glm::max(clipport.xy(), parent_vis.xy());
            clipport.zw = glm::min(clipport.zw(), parent_vis.zw());
        } else {
            clipport.xy = glm::max(clipport.xy(), parent_vis.xy());
            clipport.zw = glm::min(clipport.zw(), parent_vis.zw());
            clipport.xy = glm::min(clipport.xy(), room_vis.clipport.xy());
            clipport.zw = glm::max(clipport.zw(), room_vis.clipport.zw());
        }
        if(clipport.x >= clipport.z || clipport.y >= clipport.w) {
            return std::nullopt;
        }
        return clipport;
    }

    void get_visible_rooms(const room_id room, level_render_data& render_data, std::back_insert_iterator<decltype(level_render_data::room_nodes)> result_inserter, unsigned short count) {
        ZoneScoped;
        if(count == 0) {
            return;
        }
        for(auto& p: render_data.vis.room_infos[room].visibility_portals) {
            auto clipport = get_portal_clip_rect(p, room, render_data);
            if(clipport) {
                render_data.vis.visibility[p.room].clipport = *clipport;
                if(!render_data.vis.visibility[p.room].active) {
                    render_data.vis.visibility[p.room].active += 1;
                    *result_inserter++ = p.room;
                }
                get_visible_rooms(p.room, render_data, result_inserter, count - 1);
            }
        }
    }

This works really nice for "indoor" scenes.
It does not work well for "outdoor" scenes where rooms consists solely of portals or every outside wall are portals.
Modelling outdoor scenes with this is a common use case (and a 90s engine that does the same works just fine, albeit with limitations)
Currently, I do not cache anything - Portal visibility is computed each frame which might be the reason for overhead, because I use a local vector for it (and that one allocates/reallocates/deallocates).
Multithreading is probably out of the question since its recursive - my initial idea was to use as many threads as the very first room has portals - so each thread traverses a different root portal. But  in the case of an open area it is possible that two "paths" land on the same room and I would need to lock the access to "overlapping" rooms.
The image below shows a "worst case scenario" : you are in a corner room and the player sees everything (portals are dotted lines, rooms can be non-quadratic!)
How would someone speed up such a problem?

Before you ask "Why no bigger rooms?" : they are both culling and collision domains and are - for a level builder - easier to model, texture and lit.
Having so many small rooms for an open area is not ideal, but possible.

"Why not use bigger rooms?" - combine and cache the largest homogeneous segments as possible.  They can always be split  and recalculated later. - Just my 2 cents

You might find it useful to gather some statistics on the number of rooms that the algorithm visits, and the number of portal tests that it does. Make sure that the numbers are sensible. For example, your test case seems to cover 15x24 = 360 rooms with 4 portals each. Make sure the number of tests that you're doing makes sense, and measure the average time taken for each room.
One thing I spotted in the code is that it looks like you might do a lot of portal calculations where you end up throwing the result away because you've already visited the room. Consider checking to see if the destination room is already visited before doing the portal calculations on it.
Another possible optimization would be to special-case rooms for which every wall is a portal. The calculations for that case should be much simpler - you can probably just assume that the room on the other side of each portal is visible as long as the portal isn't back-facing to the camera.

Hi. thanks for the answer. a new clipport is applied regardless whether the room is already visited - since you can visit a room from multiple portals and then the clipport is resized to encompass all previous portals.
Regarding special-case rooms: how would I do that? I want to keep the portal clipping intact when an outdoor-area is connected to an indoor-area.

It sounds like you'll be visiting each room multiple times in outdoor areas, and that might get expensive. It might be informative to pick a single room and log how the clipport changes over time. For example, maybe it makes sense to avoid adjusting the clipport when two outdoor rooms are connected to each other, and just copy the one from the previous room - I have a feeling that the clipping won't change much in that case.

By the way, maker sure to do some profiling to double check exactly where the cost is actually coming from before you start changing things.

Apply frustum culling to eliminate rooms that are outside the view.
